# How shall I report my education and calculate my GPA?

Tags: gpa

I studied in program A, and received a master degree in A, and at the same time received a master degree in another program B by taking a certain number of courses and doing a thesis. Then I continued to study for a PhD degree in program B, but without finishing it.

In my resume for either graduate school application or job hunting,

1. How shall I report my education?

   - First master study in the two programs, and then PhD study in program B, or
   - master study in program A, and graduate study in program B receiving my master in B but not finishing PhD study in B.
2. I was wondering how to report my GPAs for my studies in program A and B? 
   In particular,

   - for my master studies, can I calculate my GPA for program A using all courses I took, and my GPA for program B using only the courses that I used to meet the master degree in B?
   - for my PhD study in program B, shall I calculate my GPA by including those courses that I took to meet the master degree in B or not?

How much flexibility do I have to calculate my GPAs? My university doesn't calculate GPAs for graduate students.

Comment: If your university doesn't provide a GPA, why would you invent one?

Comment: GPAs are required for graduate school application and job hunting.

Comment: As far as I understand, GPA is required if your university provides one… if you come from a different system, or an institution which doesn't have GPA (or that has a completely different grading system, or …) then you don't have it, period

Comment: My university is a standard one in the U.S.. It only calculate GPAs for undergraduate students. Applying to my university or others in the U.S. requires inputs of GPAs of past education.

Comment: If a graduate program is stupid enough to ask for your GPA without telling you what that means, you're free to use any reasonable definition you like.

Comment: @JeffE: thanks. I think the main reason is that my case is somewhat unusual.

Comment: What is required is a _transcript_ ...

Answer (score 2):

Since your university does not calculate your GPA, you should also not calculate a GPA unless you are told to. Most people do not care about your GPA from graduate level programs. As for reporting the PhD work, it really depends on what you did. Assuming you passed all the university requirements to be actually a PhD student, some universities require you to pass qualifying exams before you are actually a PhD student, you can list the PhD if you want. If you always intended to take the Masters and quit, you don't have to list the PhD if you do not want to.